# Android Firebase Crash in MessagingAnalytics

Tags: android, firebase, crash, firebase-cloud-messaging

## Exception

We see a lot of crashes in Google Play related to the Firebase.

The exception happens in two methods:

- com.google.firebase.messaging.MessagingAnalytics.logNotificationDismiss
- com.google.firebase.messaging.MessagingAnalytics.logNotificationReceived

**Stack Trace example:**

```
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:219)
  at com.google.firebase.messaging.MessagingAnalytics.zza (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.messaging.MessagingAnalytics.logNotificationReceived (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzd (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.zzc.run (Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run (Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:762)
```

## Investigation

We have done an investigation and found the reason:

- The exception occurs when Firebase initializes itself.
- This may happen when the device has an outdated version of Google Play Services.
- We have managed to solve this issue in app code by wrapping all Firebase calls to try / catch block.
- However, this will not help with `logNotificationDismiss` and `logNotificationReceived` as we have no control over this code.

## Google Support

We have notified the Firebase team about the issue and spent a week speaking with the support. However, they told us that they won't even look to the issue until we will send the build which reproduces the crash. Our explanation that the issue is device specific did not help.

## Question

What can we do to prevent `com.google.firebase.messaging.MessagingAnalytics` from crashing our application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have managed to solve the issue.

1. Extract AAR com.google.firebase.firebase-messaging-X.X.X.aar
2. Extract classes.jar
3. Decompile MessagingAnalytics class
4. Add try catch to **logNotificationDismiss** and **logNotificationReceived**
5. Compile MessagingAnalytics back
6. Pack to classes.jar back
7. Pack to AAR back
8. Replace AAR in project